# Strip out Special Char Sequence from XML Element

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am having a soap request which contains the one element `<NickName>\nickname</NickName>` and in my java end i am trying to strip out the special char `\n` (new line) from it so my nickname property will hold `ickname`.
At java end i am calling the below code

```
 nickName.replaceAll("[^"
                + "\u0009\r\n"
                + "\u0020-\uD7FF"
                + "\uE000-\uFFFD"
                + "\ud800\udc00-\udbff\udfff"
                + "]", "");
```

but its not stripping the new line and i am getting result as \nickname. i am expecting it should return me as `ickname`.

Comment: Are you sure `\n` in your XML file will be interpreted as newline? And not just the character sequence.

Answer (score 1):

As far as XML is concerned, `\n` is not a special character or a newline, it is a backslash followed by an `n`. If you want to match it in a regular expression, you want `\\n`.

Comment: I am using this regex but when i am passing \n then its not getting strip out value.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\[tnbrf'\"\\\\]", ""); with \\n its working fine, i also want to replace single \ with space.